# Change plural form of generated model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using this command:

```
rails generate model DayOfMonth day:integer
```

Rails generated the model "DayOfMonth" and the table "day_of_months".

I want it to create the table "days_of_month" instead.

I know this has something to do with the Inflector class and the inflector.rb in initializers folder.

But I don't understand how to get this to work.

I'm using Rails 3.

Could someone help me out here or point me to a tutorial for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just edit the migration and then add

Rails 3.2+ / 4+

```
class DayOfMonth < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = "days_of_month"
end
```

Rails 3

```
class DayOfMonth < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "days_of_month"
end
```

Comment: This syntax has now changed to 'self.table_name = "days_of_month"'

Answer (score 15):

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'day of month', 'days of month'
end
```

Read: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: it still doesn't work. I added that line, then i run "rails generate model DayOfMonth day:integer" but it still creates a migration named CreateDayOfMonths.

Answer (score 6):

You have to say what's the plural form of 'day of month' in an initializer 'inflections.rb':

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
     inflect.irregular 'day of month', 'days of month'
     inflect.irregular 'day_of_month', 'days_of_month'
end
```

That worked for me. Although, I'm still getting errors when defining associations to that model:

```
has_many :days_of_month
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Looks like there was a bug in rails that was probably causing your problem, but it's fixed now. https://github.com/arthurnn/rails/commit/c0b6e164ee6bbc7941d280ea629d70d400561668