# Pluralize 'Point of Interest' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I pluralize *Point of Interest*?

So that `PointOfInterest` becomes `PointsOfInterest`, `point_of_interest` should become `points_of_interest` and so on.

Comment: Perhaps call it an "InterestPoint"?

Comment: Yeah I don't think Rails has enough NLP in it to know that Point should be pluralized. I'd agree with @AndrewC and say change the name.

Comment: @AndrewC I had this idea too, but the boss doesn't want it that way. Until I convince him otherwise it has to be like this. Just following orders.

Answer (score 2):

You can override pluralizations this way:

In `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'PointOfInterest', 'PointsOfInterest'
  inflect.irregular 'point_of_interest', 'points_of_interest'
end
```

*See also* [Change plural form of generated model in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378316/change-plural-form-of-generated-model-in-rails/3378349#3378349)

Comment: I could've sworn that I tried this already, but it seems to have done the trick. Hope you don't mind if I fudge around with it a bit more before giving you credit for the answer.

Comment: I've called 'resources :points_of_interest' in my routes.rb, and it's still defining 'points_of_interest_index_url' instead of 'point_of_interest_url'.